# Ruby chainable method / array

Tags: ruby, arrays, chainable

How do I implement the '<<' to have the same behavior when used as a chainable method?

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :internal_array

  def initialize
    @internal_array = []
  end

  def <<(item)
    @internal_array << :a
    @internal_array << item
  end
end

t = Test.new
t << 1
t << 2
t << 3
#t.internal_array => [:a, 1, :a, 2, :a, 3]
puts "#{t.internal_array}" # => a1a2a3

t = Test.new
t << 1 << 2 << 3
#t.internal_array => [:a, 1, 2, 3]
puts "#{t.internal_array}" # => a123 , Why not a1a2a3?
```

I want both cases giving the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `self` as the last line in the << method to return it.  As is, you're implicitly returning the array, not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of the answer above:

When a method is chained, the next method is applied to the result of the first method.

For exemplo:

```
class A
  def method1
    B.new
  end
end

class B
  def method2
    C.new
  end
end

class C
  def method3
    puts "It is working!!!"
  end
end
```

The code below will work

```
A.new.method1.method2.method3
```

but the this will not

```
A.new.method1.method3.method2
```

because an instance of class B, which is the result of A.new.method1 doesn't implement method3. This is the same of:

```
(((A.new).method1).method3).method2
```

The code used in the question above, was a little bit more trick, because both, Test and Array had the method <<. But I want Test#<< to return self, and not the @internal_array that was being returned.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to your question? I'm confused.

Comment: It is the explanation of the answer above. The short answer was given by Matthew: add self at the...